# Exp:resso Store & Fedex International Economy to UK

Tags: expresso-store

I have Fedex working for domestic (US) shipping calculations, if I enter a Japanese address the international economy option works but if I enter my home UK address I get a "Destination country is not serviced." error - anyone know why this might be happening? I've tried entering a postcode with and without a space. The country dropdown is the standard Store field.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the packaging type, dropoff type, and residential delivery options affect whether or not Fedex can deliver to a specified location. Try different combinations of the settings to see whether you can get them to quote you a price for shipping to the UK.

Comment: OK I'll do that now and will post a solution if a good combo comes up!